How to use Niv to build a Stack project?
I'm working on a Haskell project using NixOS and Stack as the dependency manager. However, I'm having trouble specifying GHC version 8.8.4.
To solve the version problem, I am trying to use Niv with the following command:
$ niv add ghc -v 8.8.4 -t 'https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.8.4/ghc-8.8.4-x86_64-apple-darwin.tar.xz'

Here's my current stack-shell.nix code:
{ sources ? import nix/sources.nix { }}:
let overlay = _: pkgs: {
      ghc = (import sources.ghc {}).ghc;
    };
    pkgs = import sources.nixpkgs { overlays = [ overlay ]; config = {}; };
in with pkgs; haskell.lib.buildStackProject {
  name = "MyProject";
  buildInputs = [ zlib ];
}

How can I correctly reference GHC 8.8.4 within the haskell.lib.buildStackProject?
